# Views conditional fileds: multiple values

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type with the following field:

List (float) - blue - green - yellow

In the view, I want a condition that says that if the value is "blue" display this: div class="blue"

If it is green display class="green"

If it is empty display class ="empty"

And so on...

I tried Views Conditional Module but it can't handle multiple values...

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with a simple solution:

Added custom text field in views and something like:
div class="[field_value]"

The result of the field (blue,green,empty) is the class of the div so I can manipulate the css.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the module https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector by which you can add JS snippet in the header or footer of a page.